# Linq-to-2sql - selecting changed rows

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

In a client application I need to have all data of a table in memory. I frequently re-read data from the database to make sure I have the latest. To avoid reading all data every time I use a RowVersion/Timestamp column to only get the changed data:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CAST(RowVersion AS BIGINT) > @lastReadMaxRowVersion
```

How to do this in Linq2Sql? If I change the server data-type in the dbml to BIGINT, I get an InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something similar by performing comparisons on the [System.Data.Linq.Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary.aspx) objects which represent the RowVersion/Timestamp values in .NET.

Except, you aren't really going to compare anything. The trick is to write a LINQ-query that will be translated into `T-SQL` that does the actual comparison.

By using a method called `Compare` that takes 2 `Binary` arguments, LINQ will happily generate some `T-SQL` that compares rowversion fields in the database. It's not going to call the actual method. It's simply used to make it generate the needed SQL.

Instead of storing the latest read rowversion value as `Int64` you just store it as `Binary` instead.

```
private Binary _latestRowVersion = new Binary(new byte[] { 0 });

private void Read()
{
    using (var ctx = new DataContext())
    {
        var all =
            (from c in ctx.Categories
             where c.RowVersion.Compare(_latestRowVersion) > 0
             select c).ToList();

        if (all.Any())
        {
            _latestRowVersion =
                all.OrderByDescending(
                    p => BitConverter.ToInt64(p.RowVersion.ToArray(), 0))
                .First()
                .RowVersion;
        }
    }
}

public static class BinaryComparer
{
    public static int Compare(this Binary item1, Binary item2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```